# Changes don't reflect in simulator after cmd+r

Tags: react-native

I just started a new react-native project using react-native init myApp.

Then I started it up cding into the folder and running:

```
react-native run-ios
```

The webserver start's up and the simulator also.

When I change the index.ios.js file, for example the welcome text to something else, then hit CMD+R, the simulator refreshes but the new welcome text I inserted doesn't show.

I have tried to run react-native run-ios for every change but also with no success.

I'm on macOsx sierra 10.12.1 and react-native 0.38.0.
The simulator is running ios 10.1

Does anyone have any guess what might be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any logs in the terminal? Like anything on requests and time taken ?

Comment: check if it is debug mode or release mode from scheme

Comment: You should also check that watchman is working correctly. Had this issue last week, had to uninstall it and re-install it.

Comment: I'm in debug mode and have reinstalled watchman. I do have this error in xcode __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke Connection has no connected handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exactly same version and problem. I finally got it working by deleting the `<PREFIX>/var/run/watchman/<USER>-state` folder and running `watchman version` which recreated that folder. If you installed watchman with Homebrew I believe it's `/usr/local/var/run/watchman/<USER>-state`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thats was it! Thank you!